# Scala Array declaration - unintuitive result for apply(0)

Tags: arrays, scala, initialization, declaration

How is this possible? I have not created a new array...yet m(0) has a value of 10.
AND, m(1) is an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception...

[image]

Comment: To create an array of size 10 initialized to the default value (`0`/`false`/`\0` for primitives, `null` for objects), you want `Array.ofDim[Int](10)`.

Answer (score 1):

`val m = Array[Int](10)` means an array of type `Int` with one element `10` bound the variable `m`. `m(n)` means the n-th element of `m`.

Thats why `m(1)` gives you a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, m has only one element.

Are you mixing it up with the odd Java syntax for arrays? `int[] m = new int[10];` Which is a 10 uninitialized elements array.

Comment: No I was simply following a course...so i was not not mixing it up. Now here is the rub, if the word new is added before the Array, THEN, I get the desired effect that the courses aim was, which is to declare an Array with 10 elements that are initialised to zero. Scala is weird.

Comment: That's because `Array(10)` alone calls the method `Array.apply` in the Array object: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Array$, and using `new Array(10)` calls the constructor in class Array: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Array

Comment: But to be honest, I haven't seem many uses of `new Array` around. In fact had even forgot it existed.

Comment: Thanks for the URL's. So, what it looks like is that the Class apply and the overloaded Object apply methods are 2 different animals so to speak. This is a continual source of confusion also for a newbie in Scala, when looking up the API. Really helpful thank you.

Comment: Okay so I will answer my point about Classes and Objects in Scala. Scala segregates the static / singleton functions into what a class calls a companion Object. The two are intertwined. They can see each others private members. If anyone is reading this, feel free to correct if I have been too flippant with my choice of words.

Comment: "Scala segregates the static / singleton functions into what a class calls a companion Object." I don't think this statement makes much sense, at least not in the way it is worded. Scala simply *doesn't* have static methods. e.g.: `object X extends Y`, all methods of Y will be non-static methods in X. Not all objects are companion objects. 
It seems you need to ask another question on what are `object`s in scala.

Comment: Dude, chill, I am a newbie in Scala...your harshness is killing my Scala buzz.

Answer (score 0):

`Array[Int](10)` creates an array with one element, `10`. Check it [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html)

Still, in Scala you shouldn't access array elements directly without be aware of exceptions. I would prefer something like:

```
scala> val array = Array(10)
array: Array[Int] = Array(10)

scala> array.drop(5).headOption
res0: Option[Int] = None
```

to access the 5th element for instance

Comment: *in Scala (and any other FP language) you shouldn't access array elements directly.* Why shouldn't you access array elements directly?

Comment: Besides, to be safe you can just `array.lift(4)` to access 5th element. Your code accesses 6th as first 5 are dropped.

Comment: yes, my typo on accessing the 6th. but I was not aware of the `.lift`, thanks :)